# Gravity Sort : Is this possible programmatically?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, oop, sorting, gravity

I've been thinking recently on using the Object Oriented design in the sorting algorithm. However I was not able to find a proper way to even come closer in making this sorting algorithm that does the sorting in O(n) time.

Ok, here is what I've been thinking for a week. I have a set of input data. I will assign a mass to each of the input data (assume input data a type of `Mass` and a type of `Sphere`. If we assume all objects to be perfectly spherical objects with shapes proportional to their mass, the heaviest one touches the ground first.). I will be placing all my input data in the space all at same distance from earth. And I will make them free fall. According to gravitational law, the heaviest one hits the ground first. And the order in which they hit will give me the sorted data. This is funny in some way, but underneath I feel that this should be possible using the OO that I have learnt till date

Is it really possible to make a sorting technique that uses gravitational pull like scenario or am I stupid/crazy?

**Edit:** Turns out all objects hit the ground at the same time hence I introduced the spherical object concept.

Comment: I am not a physicist, but last I checked, two objects in free fall dropped from the same height at the same time will hit the ground at the same time (assuming no atmospheric resistance, etc.).

Comment: First of all, the heaviest one does *not* hit the ground first. If there are no other effects (air resistance being the main one) then all the objects will fall at the same rate. But that doesn't mean the jist of your idea is completely unfeasible.

Comment: Author can use windage (air drag) and the size of the object.

Comment: Oops my bad. If we assume all objects to be perfectly spherical objects with shapes proportional to their mass, the heaviest one touches the ground first.

Comment: @Bragadeesh: No. Take the time to try this: a large rock and a small rock. They hit the ground at the same moment. It's the law (of gravity).

That does not mean you can't have a program that works that way, though, but it will be a bit of a lie. ;)

Comment: @Bragaadeesh: objects fall at different speeds **only if** air resistance is a factor.  If objects are in free fall (as you state you'd like to model), they will fall at the same speed, spherical or not.

Comment: @Mpelletier @Michael. The reason I said spherical objects is when you have them in space with their center of gravities in the center, the larger one will have a huge space covering in its lower semisphere hence touching the ground first

Comment: Also, OO sorting will not let you achieve O(n) time. There's no beating the best sorting algorithms by simply doing an object oriented sort.

Comment: @Bragaadeesh: Interesting.  I'd imagine most experimenters/high-school physics teachers would start the drop with the bottoms of both objects at the same point above ground, but it does need to be defined.

Comment: @Michael Yeah, i thought it was implied, my bad

Comment: @Bragaadeesh: So in other words, they don't start at the same height. Their centres are aligned, but not the bottom. Align the bottoms and they hit the ground at the same moment. Thus, only if size is proportional to mass, and centres are aligned, is your statement true. I see.

Comment: Philosophically, the sort is now not by mass but by how high the bottom is held off the ground, which isn't quite the same thing.  Note that if you do take air resistance into account, you're into exterior ballistics.  Much of the research into computers in the US was done by the US Navy, who wanted to calculate range tables for its big guns.

Comment: @MPelletier:  Still not right.  If their centers of mass are at equal height when they are released, their centers of mass will stay aligned until one of them hits the ground.  The larger object will hit the ground first.

Comment: I would suggest not using spheres: I think it just confuses the issue.  Use vertical rods.  Much less complex to figure out size from mass (you can just say they are equal).  Unfortunately, I don't think that this ultimately will pan out as useful, but it's very interesting to explore the *why*.  Great question.

Comment: this looks like Counting sort, which for numbers of known (and reasonable) range, is O(n). But it doesn't have many practical applications

Comment: Why not view them as solid spheres of the same radius but different density?

Comment: Because if they have the same radius then they will hit the ground at the same time :)

Comment: *sigh*, please Google "Galileo".  This has nothing to do with the "Spherical Object concept", it has to do with the whole "Gravity" and "Mass" concepts.  Literally *everyone* on earth is supposed to learn this by High School.

Comment: @James McNeills (and actually everybody else):  Unless their mass is negligible in comparison to that of the Earth, the most massive one will hit the ground first:  since its own gravitational force will be larger than that of the others, the Earth will be pulled the most towards it.

Comment: @intuited: except that they are dropped at the *same* *time*!

Comment: @RBarry Young:  Yeah, so?  It actually depends on how the objects are distributed around the Earth; if they're in a two-dimensional plane and there are a lot of heavier ones on one side, the heaviest of those might hit first even though it's not the heaviest of the objects.

Comment: @intuited: This is pathetic quibbling based on conditional revisionism.  If you really think that you have confounded Galileo, Newton, etc., wrt Classical Gravitational Theory then I invite you to write it up and try to get it published.  Let us know how that works out.  Until then, Galileo's almost 500 year old experiment that many consider to mark the beginning of Science, is still considered to be established scientific fact.  Regardless of peevish attempts to quibble-cook it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung:  I was just hoping to lead the debate in a creative direction, didn't mean to offend you.  But anyway I'm not a physicist either so I did a bit of 'research', and discovered that the program `planets` agrees with me.  I used it to set up a simulation with a larger sphere in the middle and medium-sized and smaller ones on either side, then hit go.  The medium-sized one glommed on to the big middle one before the smaller one did.  So assuming that it's accurately coded, it would appear that larger objects do 'fall faster' if they're exerting a significant gravitational force.

Comment: Again, if you think that this has any relevance to anything important, then I encourage you to publish it.  I do not, I considering it pointless quibbling similar to that common to math puzzles, which is not science. So, moving on ...

Comment: This is kind of off-topic, but check out this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GcDshWmhF4A

Comment: @RBarryYoung Shame on your attitude. intuited is right. Heavier objects do "fall" faster, which can be understood when you realize that falling is not the speed imparted on the smaller object by the larger (which you are correct is the same as the Earth is the same) but is the _closing speed_ of the two objects, accounting also for the speed imparted on the larger object by the smaller one. If you want to be accurate, you need to say "for all practical purposes, objects dropped on Earth fall at the same rate."

Comment: @intuit I agree with you. One more thing to RBarryYoung: Thinking that you can detect with eyeballs or even a high-speed camera the difference in the falling speed of two human-liftable objects is a bit silly. Imagine two 5" diameter perfectly smooth spheres, one weight 5 pounds and one having the mass of the moon inside it. Do you think that they will "fall" at the same rate toward the Earth? Even if you drop the two objects at the same time, they won't hit the Earth at the same time because they are not falling in the same vector thus have different gravitational and tidal forces acting.

Comment: Again:  irrelevant, pointless quibbling.  The question posed had to do with "gravitational law", it had nothing to do with air resistance which is pretty much the only way that you can spin this to get a difference.  As for the attraction imparted on the Earth  by the spheres, you are still missing the fact that the two spheres are being dropped *at* *the* *same* *time*!  The earth cannot split in two and move towards one faster than the other.  Again, if you disagree, then I invite you to publish your brilliant debunking of Galileo.  Otherwise, it's way past time to move on ...

Comment: @RBarryYoung: I'm not sure about who said what in the annals of physics, but I'm not disproving any theories which comprehended the mutual gravitational force exerted by two (or three) bodies *on each other*.  Of course a grain of sand does not exert a significant amount of gravitational force on the Earth; but if one of the objects was, for example, the Moon, and both were "dropped" on opposite sides of the Earth, from a great height, simultaneously, the Earth would move some small amount towards the Moon, and the Moon would consequently collide with it before the sand.

Comment: Even if the Moon had somehow shrunk to the size of a grain of sand, while retaining its mass.

Comment: F = G*((m_1*m_2)/r²). When m_2 (your object) << m_1 (the earth) and r << r_earth (that is, in most practical cases), the acceleration for all objects towards Earth is equal. Only when you're working with moon-sized (and larger) and/or very far away objects, is there any difference.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The thing is, though one of the *ideas* of OOP may be to model the real world, that doesn't mean there's a direct correspondence between how long something takes in the real world and how long it would take to simulate it with a computer.

Imagine the actual steps required for your procedure:

1. An object has to be constructed for every item in your set of data. On most modern hardware, this alone would require iteration and would therefore make your strategy O(n) at *best*.
2. The effect of gravity would need to be simulated, for each object. Again, the most obvious, straightforward way to implement this would be to iterate.
3. The time that each object lands on the surface of the "Earth" in your programming model would have to be captured and, via some implementation-specific mechanism, the corresponding object would need to be inserted into an ordered list as a result.

Considering the problem further introduces additional complications. Ask yourself this: how high up do you need to position these objects to start? Obviously high enough so that the largest one actually *falls*; i.e., farther from the Earth than the radius of the largest object. But how do you know how far that is? You'd need to first determine the largest object in the collection; this, again, would (probably) require iterating. Also, one might imagine that this simulation could be multithreaded to attempt to simulate the real-time behavior of the notion of objects *actually* falling; but then you will find yourself attempting to add items to a collection (an operation which obviously takes a non-zero amount of time) potentially at the same time that new collisions are being detected. So this will create threading issues as well.

In short, I have trouble imagining how this idea could be properly implemented simply using OOP without special hardware. That said, it really *is* a good idea. It reminds me, in fact, of [Bead Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bead_sort)--an algorithm which, though not the same as your idea, is also a sorting solution that takes advantage of the very physical concept of gravity and, not surprisingly, requires specialized hardware.

Comment: THank you very much for your response. Its very insightfull. The reason I asked this question is the way people learn with examples. For example a stack, queue have real world counterparts. Even sorting techniques like quick sort/merge sort having a divide and rule concept, I can imagine to a certain extent how easy/faster things get when applied programatically. However in this specific case, I was wrong all along. Well, how else to learn? :)

Comment: @Bragaadeesh: Definitely not *wrong*! Like I said, it's actually a very clever concept. The problem is just much work would need to be done to set up the model to run the simulation that would produce your results.

Comment: Heck, lots of my more innovative ideas turn out not to work.  I just try to come up with more.

Comment: +1 I was going to mention bead sort, but you mentioned it first.

Answer (score 9):

You've just restated the problem. Calculating the order of the gravitational effects will have, at best, the O of the sort algorithms you're trying to beat.

Comment: I agree with you and think you're correct, but stating this without any support isn't much help.

Answer (score 7):

Gravitation calculation is free of charge only in real world. In programm you need to model it. It will be another n in complexity minimum

Answer (score 5):

The idea might seem simple, but the difference between the real world and the modeled one in this case is that in the real world everything is happening in parallel. To model the gravitational sort as you describe you would have to start by thinking each object on a separate thread with a thread safe way to add them to a list in the order they finish. Realistically in terms of sorting performance you would probably just use a quick sort on the times, or since they are at the same distance the rate of falling. However if your formula is proportional to the mass, you'd just skip all that and sort the mass.

Answer (score 5):

General-purpose sorting is provably at best O(n log n). To improve on this, you have to know something about the data other than just how to compare values.

If the values are all numbers, [radix sorting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) gives O(n) assuming you have upper and lower bounds for the numbers. This approach can be extended to handle any number - and ultimately, all data in a computer is represented using numbers. For example you can radix-sort strings by, in each pass, sorting by one character as if it were a digit.

Unfortunately, handling variable sizes of data means making a variable number of passes through the radix sort. You end up with O(n log m) where m is the largest value (since k bits gives you a value of up to (2^k)-1 for unsigned, half that for signed). For example, if you are sorting the integers from 0 to m-1, well - you've actually got O(n log n) again.

Translating one problem to another can be a very good approach, but sometimes it's just adding another layer of complexity and overhead.

Comment: Back in the day, when I was a college prof, I used to assign my best students the problem of proving that sorting routines that compare and swap elements in place are at best O(n log n).  Proving it for "general-purpose sorting" would require a definition of what that means.

Answer (score 3):

In a fictious "gravitational computer" this kind of sorting would take O(1) to be solved. But with the real computers like we know it, your lateral thought wouldn't help.

Comment: The computer would have to be pretty big to handle an unbounded amount of items all at once.

Comment: Fictitious?  Ha!  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vZaRgMOo-Ig

Answer (score 2):

Once you've calculated all the times they take to hit the ground, you'll still have to sort those values. You're not really gaining anything, you're just sorting different numbers after performing some extra unnecessary calculation.

**EDIT**: Whoops. Forgot physics 101. Of course they'll all hit at the same time. :)

Any sort of modeling like this just transforms one sorting problem into another one. You won't gain anything.

Comment: Why cant a hit ground operation really hits a receiver which collects the data? That way you dont have to sort the times.

Comment: You must to model (simulate) time to get the order of hits.

Comment: I don't understand. Are you thinking that you would simulate the falling objects? This doesn't really sound "object oriented".

Regardless: in addition to the fact that (as others have pointed out) gravity doesn't really work that way. But even if you used some other method of physical modeling, you'd still wind up with the same sorting problem.

Comment: They don't hit at the same time, but having a model sensitive enough to detect this would be beyond believing.

Answer (score 2):

Ignoring all the flaws that everyone else has mentioned, essentially this boils down to an `O(n^2)` algorithm, not `O(n)`. You'd have to iterate over all the "spheres", find the "heaviest" or "biggest" one, and then push it onto a list, then rinse and repeat. i.e., to find the one that hits the ground first, you have to iterate over the whole list, if it's the last one, it'd take `O(n)` time, the second would could take `O(n-1)`, etc... but worse than that, you have to perform a bunch of mathematical operations each time just to calculate some useless "time" value when you could have sorted on the value you were interested in in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmmm. Gravity sort.

Ignoring your specific model of gravity is wrong, let's see where this idea takes us.

Physical reality has 10^80 processors.

The actual lower bounds of sort is known to be log(N) if you have N/2 processors to sort N objects.

If you have several CPU cores available there's no reason you can't run mergesort on several threads.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a quite famous sorting algorithm called Spaghetti sort which is sort of similar to yours.
You can check out some of the many analyses of it on the web. e.g. on [cstheory](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/7042/is-spaghetti-sort-really-on-even-as-a-thought-experiment).

[image: spaghetti]

Answer (score 1):

I love the idea!  It is clever.  While yes what others are saying is *in general* correct, that the O(n log n) bound is a provably lower bound on the sorting problem in general, we need to keep in mind that that lower bound is true only for **comparison based** models.  What you are proposing here is a different model altogether, it does deserve further thought.

Also, as James and Matrix have pointed out, the heavier one doesn't travel faster than the lighter one, you obviously need to adapt the model to something where the heavier object (number) would indeed travel faster/further (or slower/less further) so that you can somehow distinguish the numbers (a centrifuge comes to mind as well).

Requires more thought, but your idea is sharp!

(Edit)
Now looking at Enrique's Phys2D idea, I think it makes a whole lot more sense.

One thing I would suggest is to definitely ignore the efficiency aspect for now.  (I know, I know that was the entire goal). It is a new model, and we first need to bridge the gap between the idea, and its implementation.  Only then we can comprehend what the time complexity even means for this model.

Answer (score 1):

It should be definitely only you should have proper hardware supported for it. Otherwise this sounds a very cool idea. Hope someone presents an IEEE paper to make this crazy dream visualized.

Answer (score 1):

Some weeks ago I was thinking about the same thing.

I thought to use [Phys2D](http://www.cokeandcode.com/phys2d/) library to implement it. It may not be practical but just for fun. You could also assign negative weights to the objects to represent negative numbers. With phys2d library you can define the gravity so objects with negative weight will go to the roof and objects with positive weight will fall down .Then arrange all objects in the middle between the floor and roof with the same distance between floor and roof. Suppose you have a resulting array r[] of length=number of objects. Then every time an object touches the roof you add it at the beginning of the array r[0] and increment the counter, next time an object touches the roof you add it at r[1], every time an object reaches the floor you add it at the end of the array r[r.length-1], next time you add it at r[r.length-2]. At the end objects that didn't move(stayed floating in the middle) can be added in the middle of the array(these objects are the 0's).

This is not efficient but can help you implement your idea.

Comment: Thanks Enrique.. Its great to see that there is a library for this!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem can be made simpler like this: you want to put the bottoms of the spheres at different heights so that when dropped at identical gravities the largest will hit the ground first, second largest second, etc.  This is essentially equivalent to using lines rather than spheres...in which case you can just say that heightOffTheGround = MAX_VALUE - mass.

You also don't need to worry about acceleration over time...since you don't care how fast they are going or realistic physics, you can give them all an initial velocity x, and go from there.

The problem is then that we've essentially just restated the problem and solved it like this (pseudocode):

```
int[] sortedArray; // empty
int[] unsortedArray; // full of stuff
int iVal = MAX_INT_VALUE;
while (true)
{
    foreach (currentArrayValue in sortedArray)
    {
        if (iVal = current array value
        {
            put it in my sortedArray
            remove the value from my unsortedArray
        }
    }
    if (unsortedArray is empty)
    {
        break;  // from while loop
    } 
    iVal--
}
```

The problem is that to run the physics engine, you've got to iterate over each time unit, and that will be O(1)...with a **very** large constant...the constant number of delta values that the system will run on.  The drawback is that for the very large majority of these delta values, you will essentially be getting no closer to the answer: on any given iteration, it is very likely that all the spheres/lines/whatever will have moved...but none will hit.

You could try to just say, well, let's skip a lot of intermediary steps and just jump ahead until one hits!  But that means that you have to know which one is the largest...and you're back to the sorting issue.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll adapt your idea a little. We do have our objects but they don’t differ in weight, but in speed. So, at the beginning all objects are aligned at the starting line and on the starting shot, they’ll all move with their respective velocities to the finish.

Clear enough: First object in finish will emit a signal, saying it is there. You catch the signal and write to the results paper who it was.

Okay, so you’ll want to simulate that.

We take the length of your field to be `L=1`. With step size `∆t` each of your `N` objects moves a length of `vᵢ∙∆t` at a time.
That means each object needs `sᵢ = L / (vᵢ∙∆t)` steps before reaching the finish.

The point is now, in order to distinguish between two objects with very close speeds, you’ll need to have a different step size for all of your objects.

Now, in the **best** case, this means that object 1 finishes in one step, object 2 in two and so on. Therefore, the total number of steps is `S = 1 + 2 + … + N = N∙(N + 1)/2`. This is of order `N∙N`.

If it’s not the best case and the velocities are not equally close to each other, you’ll have to lower the step size and in effect iterate many more times.

Answer (score 1):

If a computer were to be built that sorted objects based on some criteria (which is not utterly ridiculous to think about), then I believe the order of complexity would have nothing to do with the number of objects, but rather the rate of local acceleration due to gravity. Assuming it's modeled in Earth, the complexity would be O(g<sub>0</sub>) where g<sub>0</sub> is:

[image]

The simple reasoning is that the number of spherical objects `(n)` is irrelevant if their centers are aligned at start. Moreover, the acceleration due to gravity will have a much bigger impact than the height itself as it increases. For instance, if we increase the height of all objects by 10x, it wouldn't take them 10x the time to hit the ground, but much lesser. This includes various negligible approximations as the acceleration actually depends on distance between two objects, but that can be ignored as we are more interested in a bigger picture rather than a specific value.

Brilliant idea nevertheless.

Also, I love the coin sorting video posted by @Jeremy. And finally object orientedness would be the least of my concerns in building such a machine. Thinking more about it, here's my stupid two cents on building such a machine:

<strike>`O  0  o  O  o`</strike>

```
. . . . .
. . . . .
. . . . .
= = = = =
```

All objects are of varying sizes proportional to the criteria we want to sort by. They are initially held together horizontally by a thin rod that runs through the center of each sphere. The `=` at the bottom are specially designed to record a value (optionally their position) somewhere as soon as they collide with a sphere. After all spheres have collided, we will have our sorted order based on the recorded values.

Answer (score 1):

> *from [Debilski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2489190/gravity-sort-is-this-possible-programatically/2496039#2496039):*
>
> I’ll adapt your idea a little. We do
> have our objects but they don’t differ
> in weight, but in speed. So, at the
> beginning all objects are aligned at
> the starting line and on the starting
> shot, they’ll all move with their
> respective velocities to the finish.
>
> Clear enough: First object in finish
> will emit a signal, saying it is
> there. You catch the signal and write
> to the results paper who it was

I'd simplify it a step further and say these objects are random positive integers. And we want to sort them in an ascending order as they approach zero, so they have a *distance* from zero `d` which initially is equal to the integer itself.

Assuming the simulation takes place in discrete time steps i.e. *frames*, in every frame, every object's new distance would be: `d = d - v` and an object would get added to the list when its `d ≤ 0`. That is one subtraction and one conditional. Two discrete steps for each object, so the calculations seem to be O(n): linear.

The catch is, it is linear for **one frame** only! It is multiplied by the number of frames `f` required to finish. The simulation itself is O(nf): quadratic.

However, if we take the duration of a frame as the argument `t` we get the ability to affect the number of frames `f` in an inversely proportional manner. We can increase `t` to reduce `f` but this comes at the cost of accuracy, the more we increase `t`, the more the probability that two objects will finish in the same time frame therefore be listed as equivalent, even if they are not. So we get an algorithm with adjustable accuracy (as it is in most finite element simulation contexts)

We can further refine this by turning it into an adaptive+recursive algorithm. In human code it would be:

```
function: FESort: arguments: OriginalList, Tolerance
  define an empty local list: ResultList

  while OriginalList has elements
    define an empty local list: FinishedList
    iterate through OriginalList
      decrement the distance of each object by Tolerance
      if distance is less than or equal to zero, move object from OriginalList to FinishedList

    check the number of elements in FinishedList
      when zero
        set Tolerance to double Tolerance
      when one
        append the only element in FinishedList to ResultList
      when more
        append the result of FESort with FinishedList and half Tolerance to ResultList
  
  return ResultList
```

I'm wondering if there's any real similar implementation that works for someone.

Interesting subject indeed :)

*PS. The pseudocode above is my idea of pseudocode, please feel free to rewrite it in a more legible or conformant way if there is one.*

Comment: Thanks, I doubt it's useful though :) I'd say it depends much on finding a good tolerance value.

Answer (score 0):

1. I believe it is nice to mention/refer to: [What is the relation
   between P vs. NP and Nature's ability to solve NP problems
   efficiently?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11026/what-is-the-relation-between-p-vs-np-and-natures-ability-to-solve-np-problems)
   Sorting is `O(nlog(n))`, why not trying to solve NP-hard problems?
2. By the laws of physics objects fall with proportions to the
   [gravitational constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_constant) the mass is negligible.
3. Simulating a physical process can affect the actual time complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Analyse : 
(1) All centers of spheres are aligned at start
(2) greater number ==> mass higher ==> radius greater ==> distance to the ground lower
(3) in 'vacuum' same acceleration = same speed evolution ==> same distance for the center ==> how greater de radius...how earlier the sphere will hit the ground
==> conceptually OK, good physical technique if when a sphere hit the ground it can send an indentification signal + hit time ... wich will give the sorted list
Practically...not a 'good' numeric technique