# sum of maximum element of sliding window of length K

Tags: algorithm

Recently I got stuck in a problem. The part of algorithm requires to compute sum of maximum element of sliding windows of length **K**. Where **K** ranges from ***1<=K<=N*** (N length of an array).


Example if I have an array A as `5,3,12,4`
Sliding window of length 1: `5 + 3 + 12 + 4 = 24`
Sliding window of length 2: `5 + 12 + 12 = 29`
Sliding window of length 3: `12 + 12 = 24`
Sliding window of length 4: `12`

`Final answer is 24,29,24,12`.

I have tried to this **O(N^2)**. For each sliding window of length **K**, I can calculate the maximum in O(N). Since K is upto N. Therefore, overall complexity turns out to be **O(N^2)**.
I am looking for **O(N)** or **O(NlogN)** or something similar to this algorithm as N maybe upto 10^5. 
***Note:*** Elements in array can be as large as **10^9** so output the final answer as modulo *10^9+7*

***EDIT: What I actually want to find answer for each and every value of K (i.e. from 0 to N) in overall linear time or in O(NlogN) not in O(KN) or O(KNlogN) where K={1,2,3,.... N}***

Comment: Why there is down-voting in my question. Please tell the reason so that I can modify the question

Comment: Not sure about the specifics, but this seems to be related to some mathematical trick. Lets look at item `A[i]=x`. We look at all the values of the `size` of the window `1..K`. When `size=1`, `x` is the maximum. When `size` grows `x` might no longer be the maximum. Once it is not the maximum (say at `size=m`), it will NOT be the maximum any more. I think this is a key part of the solution.

Comment: Intuitively this seems very hard: it is surprising enough that it can be done O(N) for a particular K and that requires hard coding K into the data structure.  To do O(N) for all K seems very challenging.  On the other hand, if we could exploit some commonality for adjacent K then maybe O(NlogN) could be possible?

Comment: @shapiro yaacov What if given array is in increasing order or in decreasing order? Then worst case would be O(N^2). If you got better complexity then please write answer to this post.

Comment: @strubbly - I think what you said about *if we could exploit some commonality for adjacent K then..* is close to what I meant. We gain some knowledge about the array when looking at a single item and its surroundings...

Comment: Ok what if we start by zipping the list up with an index and sorting.  So in O(NlogN) we know the position of the nth largest element.  The largest is the answer for K=N.  For K=N-1 we get the largest twice, unless the largest is on the end, in which case it's the largest plus the second largest.  And so on.  Only I don't know what "and so on" means :-).

Comment: @strubbly I am getting your point. Unfortunately, this will also end up as an O(N^2) algorithm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum value of maximum values in sub-segments ... in O(n) complexity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499227/minimum-value-of-maximum-values-in-sub-segments-in-on-complexity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an abbreviated sketch of O(n).

For each element, determine how many contiguous elements to the left are no greater (call this `a`), and how many contiguous elements to the right are lesser (call this `b`). This can be done for all elements in time O(n) -- see MBo's answer.

A particular element is maximum in its window if the window contains the element and only elements among to `a` to its left and the `b` to its right. Usefully, the number of such windows of length k (and hence the total contribution of these windows) is piecewise linear in k, with at most five pieces. For example, if `a = 5` and `b = 3`, there are

```
1 window  of size 1
2 windows of size 2
3 windows of size 3
4 windows of size 4
4 windows of size 5
4 windows of size 6
3 windows of size 7
2 windows of size 8
1 window  of size 9.
```

The data structure that we need to encode this contribution efficiently is a Fenwick tree whose values are not numbers but linear functions of k. For each linear piece of the piecewise linear contribution function, we add it to the cell at beginning of its interval and subtract it from the cell at the end (closed beginning, open end). At the end, we retrieve all of the prefix sums and evaluate them at their index k to get the final array.

(OK, have to run for now, but we don't actually need a Fenwick tree for step two, which drops the complexity to O(n) for that, and there may be a way to do step one in linear time as well.)

Python 3, lightly tested:

```
def left_extents(lst):
  result = []
  stack = [-1]
  for i in range(len(lst)):
    while stack[-1] >= 0 and lst[i] >= lst[stack[-1]]:
      del stack[-1]
    result.append(stack[-1] + 1)
    stack.append(i)
  return result


def right_extents(lst):
  result = []
  stack = [len(lst)]
  for i in range(len(lst) - 1, -1, -1):
    while stack[-1] < len(lst) and lst[i] > lst[stack[-1]]:
      del stack[-1]
    result.append(stack[-1])
    stack.append(i)
  result.reverse()
  return result


def sliding_window_totals(lst):
  delta_constant = [0] * (len(lst) + 2)
  delta_linear = [0] * (len(lst) + 2)
  for l, i, r in zip(left_extents(lst), range(len(lst)), right_extents(lst)):
    a = i - l
    b = r - (i + 1)
    if a > b:
      a, b = b, a
    delta_linear[1] += lst[i]
    delta_linear[a + 1] -= lst[i]
    delta_constant[a + 1] += lst[i] * (a + 1)
    delta_constant[b + 2] += lst[i] * (b + 1)
    delta_linear[b + 2] -= lst[i]
    delta_linear[a + b + 2] += lst[i]
    delta_constant[a + b + 2] -= lst[i] * (a + 1)
    delta_constant[a + b + 2] -= lst[i] * (b + 1)
  result = []
  constant = 0
  linear = 0
  for j in range(1, len(lst) + 1):
    constant += delta_constant[j]
    linear += delta_linear[j]
    result.append(constant + linear * j)
  return result

print(sliding_window_totals([5, 3, 12, 4]))
```

Comment: It is possible to do step one in linear time - in my answer. But step two is not clear enough...

Comment: Its not clear to me though its look like you are using concept like Divide and conquer.

Comment: @Mike It's not divide and conquer.

Comment: I am not able to understand the step2

Answer (score 2):

Let's determine for every element an interval, where this element is dominating (maximum). We can do this in linear time with forward and backward runs using stack. Arrays L and R will contain indexes out of the domination interval.

To get right and left indexes:

```
Stack.Push(0) //(1st element index)
for i = 1 to Len - 1 do
     while Stack.Peek < X[i] do
         j = Stack.Pop
         R[j] = i   //j-th position is dominated by i-th one from the right
     Stack.Push(i)
while not Stack.Empty
   R[Stack.Pop] = Len  //the rest of elements are not dominated from the right

//now right to left
Stack.Push(Len - 1) //(last element index)
for i = Len - 2 to 0 do
     while Stack.Peek < X[i] do
         j = Stack.Pop
         L[j] = i   //j-th position is dominated by i-th one from the left
     Stack.Push(i)
while not Stack.Empty
   L[Stack.Pop] = -1  //the rest of elements are not dominated from the left
```

Result for (5,7,3,9,4) array.
For example, 7 dominates at 0..2 interval, 9 at 0..4

```
i  0   1   2   3   4 
X  5   7   3   9   4
R  1   3   3   5   5
L -1  -1   1  -1   4
```

Now for every element we can count it's impact in every possible sum.
Element 5 dominates at (0,0) interval, it is summed only in k=1 sum entry
Element 7 dominates at (0,2) interval, it is summed once in k=1 sum entry, twice in k=2 entry, once in k=3 entry.
Element 3 dominates at (2,2) interval, it is summed only in k=1 sum entry
Element 9 dominates at (0,4) interval, it is summed once in k=1 sum entry, twice in k=2, twice in k=3, twice in k=4, once in k=5.
Element 4 dominates at (4,4) interval, it is summed only in k=1 sum entry.

In general element with long domination interval in the center of long array may give up to k*Value impact in k-length sum (it depends on position relative to array ends and to another dom. elements)

```
k    1    2    3     4    5
 --------------------------
     5        
     7    2*7  7
     3    
     9    2*9  2*9   2*9  9
     4
 --------------------------
S(k) 28   32   25    18   9
```

Note that the sum of coefficients is N*(N-1)/2 (equal to the number of possible windows), the most of table entries are empty, so complexity seems better than O(N^2)
 *(I still doubt about exact complexity)*

Comment: Nice idea, but it's still O(N^2).

Comment: It's still O(N^2). Proof: We keep an array with a subtotal of maximums for each value of K. For each element in the original array, we would have to update X values of K in the subtotals array, where X is the size of the domination interval (e.g. an element with a domination interval of size 3 will be added to subtotals for K=1, K=2 and K=3).  So the overall complexity is the sum of the sizes of the domination intervals of all the elements.  In the worst case, that's O(N^2) - for example if the original array is in increasing order, the domination interval sizes are 1-N which sum to O(N^2).

Comment: yo! see my proof above why your algorithm is O(N^2).... no better than trivial solution. In fact, I think O(N^2) is the lowest bound, like I said in my answer.  "(I still doubt about exact complexity)" - no more doubt.....

Comment: @gen-y-s You are right about the worst case for increasing order. Sad:(

Comment: "You are right..."  - Thanks !!!  btw, not only am I right, but I also solved the question of the complexity of your algorithm, when you couldn't.   QED

Answer (score 0):

The sum of maximum in sliding windows for a given window size can be computed in linear time using a double ended queue that keeps elements from the current window. We maintain the deque such that the first (index 0, left most) element in the queue is always the maximum of the current window.

This is done by iterating over the array and in each iteration, first we remove the first element in the deque if it is no longer in the current window (we do that by checking its original position, which is also saved in the deque together with its value). Then, we remove any elements from the end of the deque that are smaller than the current element, and finally we add the current element to the end of the deque.

The complexity is O(N) for computing the maximum for all sliding windows of size K. If you want to do that for all values of K from 1..N,  then time complexity will be O(N^2). O(N) is the best possible time to compute the sum of maximum values of all windows of size K (that is easy to see). To compute the sum for other values of K, the simple approach is to repeat the computation for each different value of K, which would lead to overall time of O(N^2). Is there a better way ? No, because even if we save the result from a computation for one value of K, we would not be able to use it to compute the result for a different value of K, in less then O(N) time. So best time is O(N^2).

The following is an implementation in python:

```
from collections import deque

def slide_win(l, k):
  dq=deque()
  for i in range(len(l)):
    if len(dq)>0 and dq[0][1]<=i-k:
      dq.popleft()
    while len(dq)>0 and l[i]>=dq[-1][0]:
      dq.pop()
    dq.append((l[i],i))
    if i>=k-1:
      yield dq[0][0]

def main():
  l=[5,3,12,4]
  print("l="+str(l))
  for k in range(1, len(l)+1):
    s=0
    for x in slide_win(l,k):
      s+=x
    print("k="+str(k)+" Sum="+str(s))
```

Comment: Please read the question. I have already stated that I can find the sum for any K in O(N). But I want to find the sum over all K in complexity O(N) or in O(NlogN)

Comment: Read the code - the main function calls the slide_win function to get maximum values for all the windows, and then it computes the sum.