# Excel - Analyse the best weeks sales

Tags: excel, date

If I had a better idea how to do this, I would have been more specific in the topic ;)

I have a list of repetivite sequencial dates in column A, and the profit in column B.
I'd like to analyse which sequencial 7 days have been the most profitable.

```
01/01/2013     10
04/01/2013     15
08/01/2013     12
08/01/2013     21
09/01/2013     18
13/01/2013     20
16/01/2013     14
19/01/2013     25
```

In this example the week commencing the 13/01/13 was the most pofitable with 59.
I have 4 years to anaylse of 3000 sales.

I really appreciate any assistance or starting point.

Comment: Remove Duplicates + Pivot Table (Both are inbuilt features)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution was possible using the following code:

=SUM(INDIRECT("$B$"&MATCH(A1,$A$1:$A$10,0)):INDIRECT("$B$"&MATCH(A1+6,$A$1:$A$10,1)))

Using the MATCH function I was able to find the first CELL for the sale of the day (01/01/13), and then the CELL of the final sale of the day +6 days in (04/01/13)

Then using the INDIRECT function I SUM the two cells together to give me the largest range of sales in any 7 day period.

Thanks to those that helped and suggested good starting points.

Answer (score 2):

Add two more columns `YEAR` and `WEEKNUM` in the same sheet and do a pivot

[image]

Pivot :

[image]

Comment: + 1 For the Pivot idea. However shouldn't the duplicates be removed first?

Comment: @SiddharthRout Not necessary. This do sum(sales) group by week number and year.

Comment: Oh ok. I thought the sum for Week 2 should be calculated after removing the duplicates. But I see your point :)

Comment: The pivot table is an excellent idea, and adding a week number makes sense, however I don't want the 7 day period to necessarily start on Monday.  The best 7 days historically might have been from Wednesday-Tuesday.

Answer (score -1):

I would start by getting rid of duplicate days from the left column by adding their profits together.

Then perhaps you can apply some of the answers to this question: [How to find maximum of each subarray of some fixed given length in a given array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065926/how-to-find-maximum-of-each-subarray-of-some-fixed-given-length-in-a-given-array)

Comment: I wouldn't like to downvote this post so a request. If the user has to navigate to another SO link then what is your contribution? Either make your answer more meaningful or move your answer to a comment.

Comment: - 1 If you amend the above post, I will reverse the downvote. :)

Comment: You're right, I thought this was an appropriate comment when I posted the answer. That's a weakness in SO's reputation requirement for comments.

Comment: Then why not improve the answer ;)

Comment: This too is certainly the start of simplifying the sum.

Comment: I didn't want to answer my own question, but I certainly had a suggested solution. I could remove duplicates, and the using the OFFSET function, SUM that day + the following 7 days.