# How to efficiently keep track of the minimum value in a sliding array?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, processing-efficiency

At every iteration, two new values are added and the two oldest values are removed. How to efficiently find the minimum value at each iteration without processing the entire array again. The array starts filling from size 0 to N. Only after the entire array is filled, the removing of oldest values starts.

Comment: show you current,. ineffective, approach

Comment: When the array starts with a size of 0 you can simply check if one of the new values is the smallest

Comment: I think you are looking for a Binary Heap array based implementation. You can take a look at this http://www.sanfoundry.com/java-program-implement-binary-heap/

Comment: If you compare a running minimum against incoming values, you'll only have to iterate when it hits the bottom. That should keep the cost at `O((1/n)*n)` or `O(1)`.

Comment: You can reduce this "sliding array" problem easily to a queue data structure, and then the problem boils down to "how do I efficiently find min in a queue DS". [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4802038/572670) discusses how to achieve this