# Find the largest contiguous subarray such that a function of the elements in the subarray is less than the given value

Tags: arrays, algorithm

## Question

I'm looking for an algorithm that can efficiently compute the largest allowable contiguous subarray where the function PowerUsed(subarray) is less than the parameter AllowedEnergy.  Each element in the array contains two values, startingEnergyUsed and ContinuousEnergyUsed, and PowerUsed is computed given two arrays of the same size denoting the startingEnergy and continuousEnergy values associated with each element (example below). The solution needs to be better than O(n^2) time complexity, and ideally would be O(n) space complexity or less.

### Given:

- std::vector startingEnergyUsed
- std::vector continuousEnergyUsed
- long AllowedEnergy

### Constraints:

- startingEnergyUsed.size() == continuousEnergyUsed.size()
- 1 <= startingEnergyUsed.size() <= 2^32 - 1
- 0 <= startingEnergyUsed[i] <= 2^32 - 1
- 0 <= continuousEnergyUsed[i] <= 2^32 - 1
- PowerUsed(x) <= LONG_MAX for any subvector x
- 0 < AllowedEnergy <= LONG_MAX

```
long PowerUsed(std::vector<int> & StartingEnergyUsed, std::vector<int> & ContinuousEnergyUsed)
{
    long powerUsed = std::max_element(StartingEnergyUsed.begin(), StartingEnergyUsed.end());
    long totalContinuousEnergy = std::accumulate(ContinuousEnergyUsed.begin(),ContinuousEnergyUsed.end());
    powerUsed += totalContinuousEnergy * ContinuousEnergyUsed.size();
    return powerUsed;

}
```

### Additional details:

For reference, my current solution is the standard naïve O(n^2) solution involving iterating over each element and adding elements to it until the combined subvector exceeds AllowedEnergy and then trying again from the next element. I have minor improvements involving ignoring subarrays lower than my current max, but nothing that improves the big O time complexity.

The information I've provided is in C++ as that is what I've been using to work on the problem, but since this is an algorithm question I'm open to any solution based in procedural or object oriented languages.

Comment: In its most general form, you're going to do even worse than O(n^2): see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem .

Comment: Largest as in "longest subarray" or "maximum value"

Comment: Using a pretty heavy restriction on the "formula" (so cutting us away from the general case) and array of positives, the requirement of contiguity makes it so that each subarray starting at _i will have one, and only one, optimum length; and you can determine this using a rolling of the array, subtracting A[_i] when advancing and adding A[l_i], A[l_i+1], ... as required, finally keeping track of the desirability of the l_i-long array starting at _i (closeness to the target, number of items...). **This** restriction, off the top of my head, *should* run in o(n).

Comment: And I don't really get your `PowerUsed` function. Maybe you can elaborate with some example data?

Comment: Largest as in "longest subarray", apologies for any confusion there.

Comment: Regarding the PowerUsed function, let me see if I can explain it a bit better. It's divided into 2 parts, the first is the maximum of all startingEnergyUsed values in the subarray. The second is the sum of all continuousEnergyUsed values in the subarray multiplied by the number of elements in the subarray.

Comment: For an example: given startingEnergyUsed subarray {1, 3, 5, 7, 9} and continuousEnergyUsed subarray {4, 2, 8, 6} the PowerUsed would be computed as follows. Max(startingEnergyUsed) = 9, Sum(continuousEnergyUsed) = 20, PowerUsed = 9 + 20 * 4 = 89.

Comment: Can you post your existing solution? LSerni's comment basically answered this: use a sliding window with a max-queue to track the maximum.

Comment: The question of the sliding window is can you recompute its desirability in constant time? From my understanding, you have no guarantee that optimum length m is << n, so even with a sliding window you're forced to perform O(m) calculations at each step, and if m is not greatly lower than n that's still O(n^2). It is still better than my initial computation though, since I was effectively creating a new queue at each step. If someone wants to propose that solution I'll probably accept it. Especially if they can show that it's O(n).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `PowerUsed` function, given indices `[L, R]` representing subarray endpoints, breaks down into

```
max(StartingEnergyUsed[L, ... R]) 
+ (R - L + 1) * sum(ContinuousEnergyUsed[L, ... R])
```

Since all array values are positive, this function is **monotonic** with respect to subarray inclusion (i.e. expanding a subarray will never make the function smaller).

This means you can use a sliding window to find the maximum length in linear time, if you can maintain `PowerUsed` for your window in (amortized) constant time per operation as you add elements on the right of the window and remove them on the left. The sum can be maintained easily, the maximum needs a few more lines of code.

Since the sliding window is really a Queue, what you need is a [Queue in which push_rear(), pop_front() and get_max() are all constant time operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4802038/implement-a-queue-in-which-push-rear-pop-front-and-get-min-are-all-consta). Technically that post asks for 'get_min', but taking any of the many existing answers there and replacing 'min' with 'max' will give you a Max-Queue with all amortized-constant-time operations.

A Max-Queue is just two double ended queues and a few lines of code. For example, here's a c++ Max-Queue implementation from modifying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19085171/16757174):

```cpp
#include <deque>

std::deque<int> main_queue;
std::deque<int> max_queue;

void PushRear(int elem)
{
  main_queue.push(elem);

  while(!max_queue.empty() && elem > max_queue.back())
  {
      max_queue.pop_back();
  }

  max_queue.push_back(elem);
}

void PopFront() 
{
  int elem = main_queue.front();
  main_queue.pop();

  if (elem == max_queue.front())
  {
       max_queue.pop_front();
  }
}

int GetMax() 
{
return max_queue.front();
}
```

Given that, here's pseudocode for your function. If you believe that the Max-Queue has constant time operations, this function must have linear complexity, since it's just a single loop from `0 to n` with an (amortized) constant number of operations per iteration.

```cpp
longest_length = 0;
left_index = 0;
window_sum = 0;
MaxQueue = new MaxQueue();

for (int right_index = 0; right_index < StartingEnergyUsed.size(); right_index += 1){

    window_sum += ContinuousEnergyUsed[right_index];
    MaxQueue.Push_Back(StartingEnergyUsed[right_index]);
    
    if (window_sum * (right_index-left_index+1) + MaxQueue.GetMax() >= AllowedEnergy){
        window_sum -= ContinuousEnergyUsed[left_index];
        MaxQueue.PopFront();
        left_index += 1;
    }

    if (right_index-left_index+1 > longest_length &&
     window_sum * (right_index-left_index+1) + MaxQueue.GetMax() < AllowedEnergy) {

         longest_length = right_index - left_index + 1;
     }
}

return longest_length;
```

Comment: Thanks kcsquared, that looks like a perfect solution. I hadn't thought that you could make the necessary queue functions constant time, and doing so neatly fixes up my remaining issues!