# Design a stack + findmin and deletemin in O(1)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack

I saw this answer to the question about designing a stack with findmin in O(1) time:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3435998/2653179

What if the request is the same:

```
Devise a stack-like data structure that does push, pop and min (or max) operations 
in O(1) time. There are no space constraints.
```

But deletemin also should be in O(1)? Is it possible?

Comment: No `deletemin` is not possible in O(1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No. It cannot be done - because it will allow `O(n)` sorting.**

```
Assume there is such a DS, let it be D
Let A be an input array.
push all elements from A to D.
while D is not empty:
   yield D.min()
   D.popMin()
```

The above will run in `O(n)` assuming `popMin()` and `min()` are `O(1)`, and will sort an array.

However, sorting is Omega(nlogn) problem. Contradiction. 

Thus we can conclude such a DS does not exist,