# Basics, data structures challenges, Max number in the stack

Tags: java, data-structures

Hey guys i have some data structure challenges that i really don't know how to solve better.

I had a correct solution but the time exceed some limit, the code should follow N instructions:

- add X number to a stack when I type 1
- delete the top of the stack with 2
- and print the max number in the stack with 3

[that way](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwWfz.png)

It it suposed to be solved with arrays, arraylists, stack, queues or trees. That is what I did, but it exceed 6.51 s:

```
import java.util.*;

class Main {

public static void maxStack(int a, int val, Stack stack) {

    switch (a) {
        case 1:
            stack.add(val);
            break;
        case 2:
            if (stack.isEmpty()) {
                break;
            }
            int c = (int) stack.pop();
            break;
        case 3:

            Object o[] = stack.toArray();
            Arrays.sort(o);
            System.out.println(o[o.length - 1]);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    int val = 0;

    int a = scan.nextInt();
    while (a-- > 0) {
        int t = scan.nextInt();
        if (t == 1) {
            val = scan.nextInt();
        }
        maxStack(t, val, stack);
    }
    scan.close();
}
}
```

Any recommendation?

Comment: Warning: you are using raw types, i.e. `Stack` instead of `Stack<Integer>`. Using raw types is only allowed for backward-compatibility, and should not be written in new code.

Comment: Then maybe you need a better way to keep track of the maximum item on the stack. I suggest you study https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-a-stack-that-supports-getmin-in-o1-time-and-o1-extra-space/, but rather than keeping track of the smallest item, you keep track of the largest.

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeding the time because each time you're performing the `sort` operation on them. This problem can be solved in two ways

1. using O(1) time and O(n) space using an auxiliary stack
2. using O(1) time and O(1) space

[insert, delete, max in O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3435926/insert-delete-max-in-o1)